# "level of attributes attachment" for a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have a fully functioning code snippet where I create some HTML elements and then turn them into objects using a "factory" type of function:

```
function Control(HTMLelem) {
    this.target = HTMLelem;
    this.target.clickPoint = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
    this.target.lastMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
    this.target.currentMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
    // so no so forth
}
```

question is:
- I am currently attaching all the new properties (like clickPoint) to the this.target, basically to the html element. But I could I guess do that also for the "this" so that it was something like:

```
function Control(HTMLelem) {
    this.target = HTMLelem;
    this.clickPoint = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
    this.lastMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
    this.currentMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
    // so no so forth
}
```

So what is the difference if any?

Comment: In the first you are attaching the properties to the HTML element: the argument in `new Control(elem)`. In the second the instance object created by `new Control(elem)`. It's not clear *why* you're doing any of this, why you need a constructor (it's not a factory) at all instead of just attaching properties to the HTML element directly.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `HTMLelem.clickPoint = ....` and `HTMLelem.lstMove = ...`, etc.? Why are you making it more complicated?

Comment: Hey guys, ty for your answers. I think I am doing it cause someone else was doing it;( But I think I wanted the constructor cause I am producing a lot of those elements

Comment: But you are not producing anything really. You are just setting properties on the DOM element. Unless there is more to it that you haven't shown here, you should just have a simple function you pass the element to.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `this` binding when you use your `Control` factory:

```
function Control(){
    this.innerHTML = 'foo';
    // ...
    return this;
}

let e = Control.bind(document.createElement('p'))()
console.log(e.innerHTML); // => 'foo';
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xt3anu68/1/)

Comment: Why use `this` at all then and not just pass the element as parmeter and do `ele.innerHTML = ...; return ele;` ? Just like any other function would work.

Comment: That's a great point actually. I guess I just went this route to be in line w/ OP's original code.

Comment: And (a bit off-topic) but, don't use `.innerHTML` when you are not providing actual HTML as a value. Use `.textContent` for that.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting! but I still wanted to understand cons/pros of attaching attributes at different "levels". Maybe I am not asking the right question here;( But at least I want to learn what is better from performance POV - to attach attributes to HTML elements directly?